# how to write a regex expression extract hadoop mr counter data from stderr logfile

Tags: python, regex, hadoop

how to write a regex expression extract hadoop mr counter data from stderr logfile,

how to findall `\t` line with `\t\t` line pair data, I wrote a regular (`re.findall(r'(\t[a-zA-Z\s]+)\n(.*?)\n\t\w+', text, re.S|re.M)`) but it is not correct

[image]

this is the stderr log sample

```
23/01/16 14:26:13 INFO mortbay.log: Conf is not init.
23/01/16 14:26:14 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 246
    File System Counters
        FILE: Number of bytes read=104971581500
        FILE: Number of bytes written=287906526786
        FILE: Number of read operations=0
        FILE: Number of large read operations=0
        FILE: Number of write operations=0
        HDFS: Number of bytes read=758223470025
        HDFS: Number of bytes written=97994290043
        HDFS: Number of read operations=24275
        HDFS: Number of large read operations=0
        HDFS: Number of write operations=2000
        VIEWFS: Number of bytes read=0
        VIEWFS: Number of bytes written=0
        VIEWFS: Number of read operations=0
        VIEWFS: Number of large read operations=0
        VIEWFS: Number of write operations=0
    Job Counters 
        Killed map tasks=3
        Killed reduce tasks=2
        Launched map tasks=6427
        Launched reduce tasks=1002
        Other local map tasks=33
        Data-local map tasks=3746
        Rack-local map tasks=2648
        Total time spent by all maps in occupied slots (ms)=358061940
        Total time spent by all reduces in occupied slots (ms)=858021936
        Total time spent by all map tasks (ms)=119353980
        Total time spent by all reduce tasks (ms)=107252742
        Total vcore-milliseconds taken by all map tasks=119353980
        Total vcore-milliseconds taken by all reduce tasks=107252742
        Total megabyte-milliseconds taken by all map tasks=305546188800
        Total megabyte-milliseconds taken by all reduce tasks=878614462464
    Map-Reduce Framework
        Map input records=30951997
        Map output records=30951997
        Shuffled Maps =6425000
        Failed Shuffles=46
        Merged Map outputs=6425000
    File Input Format Counters 
        Bytes Read=0
    File Output Format Counters 
        Bytes Written=0
23/01/16 14:26:14 INFO streaming.StreamJob: Output directory:
+ [[ 0 -ne 0 ]]
+ exit 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could match a lines starting with a single tab, followed by 1 or more lines that start with 2 tabs and a non whitespace character:

You can also only use `re.M`

```
^\t[a-zA-Z].*(?:\n\t\t\S.*)+
```

See a [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/MPuVmU/1).

If the rest of the line can also be empty after matching 2 tabs, you can just only `.*`

```
^\t[a-zA-Z].*(?:\n\t\t.*)+
```

See another [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/CGkVKe/1).